# Handling a command line executable within in Python 2X via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, executable

I am wanting to run an executable that would normally be run directly on the command line but ultimately via a Python script. 
I used subprocess.Popen after reading through here and multiple Google results to achieve some limited success.

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>exe_path = sys.argv[1]
>>>dir_path_in = sys.argv[2]
>>>dir_path_out = sys.argv[3]
>>>subprocess.Popen([exe_path])
```

It then displays

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x021B7B30>
```

Followed by

```
>>>usage: <path to exe> [options] <dir_path> <dir_path_out>
```

But if I enter what you would normally expect to on the command line if used exclusively it returns:

```
>>>SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I have tested what is entered exclusively on the command line with the exe and it works fine just not via Python

I have had a look through StackOverFlow and the best kind of comparison I found was here [How to handle an executable requiring interactive responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498468/how-to-handle-an-executable-requiring-interactive-responses)

Ultimately the "usage" part will not even be required in the end as the declared sys.argvs will provide all the information the executable requires to run automatically.

Comment: show the full traceback (including the line with the broken code). Note: the usage output suggests that to run the command waiting until it ends, you could: `subprocess.check_call(sys.argv[1:4])`

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess.call() achieved the desired result by declaring the argv variables and then concatenating the variables and using that final variable in a subprocess.call() as opposed to using shlex.split() which I first tried but it struggled with paths even with the '\' escaped for Windows

```
import subprocess
exe_path = sys.argv[1]
dir_path_in = sys.argv[2]
dir_path_out = sys.argv[3]
command = exe_path, dir_path_in, dir_path_out
p = subprocess.call(command)
```